# Is it possible to stop word wrap in as3 textarea spark component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, word-wrap

I want to stop the word wrap "i.e long words should not be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line" in textarea spark component.

So anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: check if there's a flag for scrolling. Also normal `TextField` has a flag for word-wrapping, check if there is a similar flag in spark textarea.

Comment: Hi @Vesper , property `lineBreak="explicit"` works for me to stop word wrap in textarea spark component. Thanks

Comment: You should post that as a self-answer for others to see that this question has an answer, and probably receive some respect from others. :)